# Synchronize conversation error for twilio conversation sdk

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I have followed [Android quickstart conversations project](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/conversations-quickstart-android)
I am facing a crash with following details -

```
com.twilio.conversations.ListenerException: Exception thrown by a listener. Your application might have a problem in listener implementation. Listeners must never throw uncaught exceptions. See 'Caused by:' below for more details.
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at com.twilio.conversations.internal.RethrowingForwarder$RethrowingProxy.invoke(RethrowingForwarder.java:123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
        at $Proxy10.onSuccess(Unknown Source)
        at com.twilio.conversations.internal.CallbackListenerForwarder$1.run(CallbackListenerForwarder.java:34)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Messages are not available at the moment. Synchronize the conversation first.
        at com.twilio.conversations.ConversationImpl.getMessages(ConversationImpl.java:214)
        at com.twilio.conversations.ConversationImpl.getLastMessages(ConversationImpl.java:282)
        at QuickstartConversationsManager.loadPreviousMessages(QuickstartConversationsManager.java:222)
        at QuickstartConversationsManager.access$600(QuickstartConversationsManager.java:43)
        at QuickstartConversationsManager$3.onSuccess(QuickstartConversationsManager.java:156)
        at QuickstartConversationsManager$3.onSuccess(QuickstartConversationsManager.java:147)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.twilio.conversations.internal.RethrowingForwarder$RethrowingProxy.invoke(RethrowingForwarder.java:121)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006) 
        at $Proxy10.onSuccess(Unknown Source) 
        at com.twilio.conversations.internal.CallbackListenerForwarder$1.run(CallbackListenerForwarder.java:34) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Any ideas on what is missing or what is wrong?

Comment: Hey and welcome. Please share the code as well. Only the error is a bit to less information.

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: Please let me know if anyone figures out the solution to this because I've been stuck on this bug for days and am running out of possible solutions

Answer (score 3):

I know this has been a while, but I experienced this issue while moving from Twilio Chat to Twilio Conversation. How I fixed it was to wrap the method you are calling in a synchronization Status check.

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Messages are not available at the moment. Synchronize the conversation first.` is meaning conversation may be out of sync.

```
    if (conversation?.synchronizationStatus?.isAtLeast(Conversation.SynchronizationStatus.ALL) == true)  {
      conversation?.setAllMessagesRead { value -> Timber.v("Unread Count:" + value) }
    }
```

Here is twilio documentation about what do if your conversation is out of sync or what to do with the else statement.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/best-practices-sdk-clients#mobile-sdks-specifics

Comment: That's correct before getting messages from the conversation we should make sure that the conversation should be synchronized.